# How to install angular extension packs into VS Code correctly

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code

I've tried to install multiple VS Code extensions for angular (ie Angular 2 TypeScript Emmet, Bracket Pair Colorizer, HTML CSS Class Completion, etc) but none are working. I've reloaded vs code after each install and still nothing is reflected. Has anyone run into this problem and found a solution?

Comment: How _precisely_ are they "not working"?

Comment: They aren't being reflected when I'm coding. So for example, class completion selections aren't being displayed for me (which is what should happen for the HTML CSS Class Completion extension).

Comment: how did you load these extensions?

Comment: VS code has an extensions marketplace on the UI, I downloaded it from there